# Problems while installing libelf on macOS with Macports

Tags: macos, macports

I have tried to run `sudo port -d install libelf` on macOS with Macports. However, that failed and told me `neither int nor long is 32-bit`. How can I deal with that ? I'll be very appreciated anyone can help me.

Comment: This issue has been reported here: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/61564

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in the libelf software for which [MacPorts added a fix](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/61564). In the future, you can get faster help for such problems by reporting the problems directly to the developers of the software or to MacPorts so that somebody can begin working on the fix.